# itertools product function two elements at a time in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, python-itertools, cartesian-product

I have the following list:

```
L = [0, 25, 50, 75, 100]
```

I want to find all the possible combinations for this list but two elements at a time, e.g:

```
Combi = [(0, 0), (0, 25), (25,0), (25, 25), (0, 0), (0, 50), (50, 0), (50, 50), (0, 0), (0, 75), (75, 0), (75, 75)...]
```

and so on.

Is there a concise way to achieve this?

Comment: This is covered in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).  Use the argument `repeat=2`

Comment: `list(combinations_with_replacement(L, 2))`?

Comment: @Prune that gives me the combinations as `(0, 0), (0, 25), (0, 50)...` etc. I want the result like I have mentioned with repeat combinations for each pair.

Comment: @deadshot that also is not giving me repeat combinations for each pair. anything else I can try?

Comment: `list(combinations_with_replacement(L, 2)) + list(combinations_with_replacement(L[::-1], 2))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want a product of all unique pairs in the input. You can tie together three `itertools` functions to achieve this:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations, product

L = [0, 25, 50, 75, 100]

print(list(chain.from_iterable(product(pair, repeat=2) for pair in combinations(L, 2))))
```

Output matches your spec:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 25), (25, 0), (25, 25), (0, 0), (0, 50), (50, 0), (50, 50), (0, 0), (0, 75), (75, 0), (75, 75), (0, 0), (0, 100), (100, 0), (100, 100), (25, 25), (25, 50), (50, 25), (50, 50), (25, 25), (25, 75), (75, 25), (75, 75), (25, 25), (25, 100), (100, 25), (100, 100), (50, 50), (50, 75), (75, 50), (75, 75), (50, 50), (50, 100), (100, 50), (100, 100), (75, 75), (75, 100), (100, 75), (100, 100)]
```

If you want to push *all* the work to the C layer (no generator expression byte code execution per combination), another import (and some even more excessively dense code) can get you there:

```
from functools import partial

print(list(chain.from_iterable(map(partial(product, repeat=2), combinations(L, 2)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
out=[]
for c in list(it.combinations(L,2)):
  out.extend (it.product(c, repeat=2))
```

[image]

Comment: You (almost) never need to wrap the thing you're iterating over in the `list` constructor (the rare exception is when you're mutating the thing you're iterating over, not the case here). `for c in it.combinations(L, 2):` will do the job without wastefully making a temporary `list`.

Comment: Yes, you are right thanks

Answer (score 0):

some way to do it using list comprehension:

```
list = [0, 25, 50, 75, 100]
new_list = [(list[i], j) for i in range(len(list)) for j in list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, if i understand you correctly:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

L = [0, 25, 50, 75, 100]

combi = []
for a,b in combinations_with_replacement(L, 2):
    combi.append((a,b))
    if a != b:
        combi.append((b,a))
```

gives:

```
[(0, 0),
 (0, 25),
 (25, 0),
 (0, 50),
 (50, 0),
 (0, 75),
 (75, 0),
 (0, 100),
 (100, 0),
 (25, 25),
 (25, 50),
 (50, 25),
 (25, 75),
 (75, 25),
 (25, 100),
 (100, 25),
 (50, 50),
 (50, 75),
 (75, 50),
 (50, 100),
 (100, 50),
 (75, 75),
 (75, 100),
 (100, 75),
 (100, 100)]
```